# when rotation shape changed in metal

Tags: swift, textures, metal, metalkit

I just created a rectangle  using four vertices in metal. I just need to rotate it. So I use a model metrics.Here is my vertex shader.

```
vertex VertexOutTexture vertex_shader_texture(const VertexInTexture vertices [[stage_in]],
                                              constant ModelConstant &modelConstants[[buffer(1)]],

    VertexOutTexture v;
    v.position =  modelConstants.modelMatrix*float4(vertices.position,1);
    v.color = vertices.color;
    v.textureCoordinates = vertices.textureCoordinates;

    return v;

}
```

it rotate. But shape is changed. So I used projection transformation which converts the node’s coordinates from camera coordinates to normalized coordinates.
I create projrction matrix:

```
var sceneConstants = ScenceConstants()
```

set its value:

```
sceneConstants.projectionMatrix = matrix_float4x4(prespectiveDegreesFov:45, aspectRatio:Float(1.0),nearZ:0.1,farZ:100)
```

where init mathod is in math.h

```
init(prespectiveDegreesFov degreesFov:Float, aspectRatio:Float,nearZ:Float,farZ:Float){
       let  fov = radians(fromDegrees: degreesFov)

        let y = 1/tan(fov*0.5)
        let x = y/aspectRatio
        let z1 = farZ/(nearZ - farZ)
        let w = (z1*nearZ)

        columns = (
            float4(x,  0,  0,  0),
            float4(0,  y,  0,  0),
            float4(0,  0,  z1,-1),
            float4(0,  0,  w,  0)
        )
    }
```

send commands to GPU:

```
commandEncoder.setVertexBytes(&sceneConstants, length: MemoryLayout<ScenceConstants>.stride, index: 2)
```

change my vertex shader:

```
v.position = sceneConstants.projectionMatrix* modelConstants.modelMatrix*float4(vertices.position ,1 );
```

But it did not work.

before rotation:[image]

after rotation:[image]

I have atached math functions I am using  below.

```
func radians(fromDegrees degrees:Float) ->Float{
    return (degrees/100)*Float(Double.pi)
}
extension matrix_float4x4 {

    init(prespectiveDegreesFov degreesFov:Float, aspectRatio:Float,nearZ:Float,farZ:Float){
       let  fov = radians(fromDegrees: degreesFov)

        let y = 1/tan(fov*0.5)
        let x = y/aspectRatio
        let z1 = farZ/(nearZ - farZ)
        let w = (z1*nearZ)

        columns = (
            float4(x,  0,  0,  0),
            float4(0,  y,  0,  0),
            float4(0,  0,  z1,-1),
            float4(0,  0,  w,  0)
        )
    }



    mutating func scale(axis: float3){

        var result = matrix_identity_float4x4
        let x :Float  = axis.x
        let y :Float  = axis.y
        let z :Float  = axis.z


        result.columns = (

            float4(x,0,0,0),
            float4(0,y,0,0),
            float4(0,0,z,0),
            float4(0,0,0,1)
        )

        print("self:\(self)")
        self = matrix_multiply(self, result)

    }


    mutating func translate(direction: float3){

        var result = matrix_identity_float4x4

        let x :Float  = direction.x
        let y :Float  = direction.y
        let z :Float  = direction.z


        result.columns = (
            float4(1,0,0,0),
            float4(0,1,0,0),
            float4(0,0,1,0),
            float4(x,y,z,1)
        )
        print("self:\(self)")
        self = matrix_multiply(self, result)
    }


    mutating func rotate(angle: Float ,axis: float3){

        var result = matrix_identity_float4x4

        let x :Float  = axis.x
        let y :Float  = axis.y
        let z :Float  = axis.z

        let c: Float = cos(angle)
        let s:Float = sin(angle)

        let mc :Float = (1 - c)

        let r1c1: Float = x * x * mc + c
        let r2c1: Float = x * y * mc + z * s
        let r3c1: Float = x * z * mc - y * s
        let r4c1: Float = 0.0

        let r1c2: Float = y * x * mc - z * s
        let r2c2: Float = y * y * mc + c
        let r3c2: Float = y * z * mc + x * s
        let r4c2: Float = 0.0

        let r1c3: Float = z * x * mc + y * s
        let r2c3: Float = z * y * mc - x * s
        let r3c3: Float = z * z * mc + c
        let r4c3: Float = 0.0

        let r1c4: Float = 0.0
        let r2c4: Float = 0.0
        let r3c4: Float = 0.0
        let r4c4: Float = 1.0


        result.columns = (
            float4(r1c1,r2c1,r3c1,r4c1),
            float4(r1c2,r2c2,r3c2,r4c2),
            float4(r1c3,r2c3,r3c3,r4c3),
            float4(r1c4,r2c4,r3c4,r4c4)
        )
        print("Result:\(result)")
        self = matrix_multiply(self, result)
    }


}
```

How can I fix this issue?Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you show us the model matrix you're using?

Comment: I just appended it .Check it

Comment: Okay, but what parameters are you passing to `rotate`? Is `axis` definitely a unit vector? Also, I wouldn't expect a rectangle to stay a rectangle under rotation if the aspect ratio of the view isn't being taken into account. Have you tried passing in the actual aspect ratio when creating the projection matrix, rather than hard-coding it to 1.0?

Comment: I am considering UIRotationGestureRecognizer & pass the  rotateGesture.rotation value & change model matrix accordingly. I have triyed aspect ratio = Float(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height) too. Did not work

Comment: private var modelMatrix= ModelMatrix() ,
struct ModelMatrix {
   var modelMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4
}

Comment: BTW It works for squre,but not for rectangle.

Comment: So that means there probably isn't a shearing component to the transform, but there's still some kind of non-uniform scaling going on (probably in the viewport transform). Can you share the complete project source?

Comment: sure..here is github repo link https://github.com/kASUNSithira/RayBreak

Comment: Seems to work when I plug the actual aspect ratio of my device into the projection matrix calculation.

Comment: actually it is not expected to be a square. Sometimes it appears as a square. Then it works fine. Even in iphone with 16:9 ratio it won't work if you rotate the device. I just tried with an ipad with 4:3 aspect ratio

Comment: What aspect ratio are you using for an iPad in landscape orientation? It should be 1.333.

Comment: It was my mistake.I was given vertices for a square & expected a rectangle. When I change vertices matches to rectangle it worked fine.